# Update Service Reference is not working in WCF

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2012

I am using VS 2012.

I add services reference to my WPF project, but when I've changed my services and updated service reference my Reference.svcmap -> Reference.CS file will be blank and I can't use reference anymore. I can see it in project, but I can't use.

My settings of Services References are :-
[image]

Reference.cs file

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.17929
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What about using svcutil to generate the service reference ?

Comment: delete the service reference from your project and clean the solution again add it with the same name and test

Comment: @Damith  I try right now. and this time reference is added but there is no Methods and nothing will come to my ClientApplication

Comment: @cvraman I dn't know how to do it with svcutil to generate the webservices refe.

Comment: @ujjaval The one way i solve this problem restart the Visual Studio..give a try

Comment: @Pratik I restart the vs 2012  devenv /resetsettings  but no luck for me  :(

Comment: @ujjaval : See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751905.aspx link on how to use svcutil. 

As an example:
svcutil.exe "http://localhost/MyService.svc" /t:code

Comment: What happens when you browse the URL?

Comment: @alan my url is like :- net.tcp://localhost:5054/player/mex so i can not see in browser.  I have console application and in that  IPlayerService.cs and  PlayerService.cs

Comment: run your service host app and then try to update the service reference...

Answer (score 30):

uncheck the Reuse types in referenced assemblies checkbox and put address of your new service in Address textbox.

Comment: +1, but the problematic option is "Reuse types in all referenced assemblies" alone. If you uncheck this problematic option and choose the proper assemblies from the list, the generated class should be OK.

Comment: Thanks, been having trouble with my service reference as well, this was the answer I needed. I can now just use my EF objects. (in the form of an array but still)

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly. I only needed to Update the service reference once again.

Answer (score 4):

While configuring service reference append **/mex** (address of your end point with mexHttpBinding ) at the end of your service URL.

> https://service.domain.com/serivce1.svc/mex

This will enable **metadata exchange**. So Reference.cs will be modified / added (if you are adding service reference for the first time).

**Edit** : On analysis I found that this issue happens when a service (which implements one ServiceContract) is exposed via more than one end point.

This issue can be avoided by using different Service Contracts (Interface) for each end point and making the service class (service1) implement all these Interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot browse the URL, then you will not be able to add the service reference.  Try hosting your web service locally in IIS.  When you're able to browse the URL, then you can add the service reference.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things you can do first Clean the solution, delete the output directory and the service reference. Restart the Visual Studio and re configure the web service.

Comment: how can i delete the output directory  ? can you please tell me

Comment: @ujjaval in solution explorer there is a button "show All files" when you click that you can see the 'Bin', `Obj` Folders

Comment: ok I delete all the dll and compile file and then restart the VS 2012 and again re configure but still same issue. :(

Answer (score 1):

Unchecking the reuse option the Update Service option works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by Team Foundation source control.
Try to right click on the service ref and choose "Check out for edit..."
Than update service reference again.

Comment: This is a question from 2013. So, the value in providing an answer now would be for future users who might have similar issues. Consequently, answers to old questions like this should only be provided if they can clearly identify the problem and explain/provide a solution.